# Stacked area plot not showing negative values properly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stacked area plot. I have been able to do so for the most part except that one of the variables has negative values and it is not being displayed properly. Here's what my data looks like:

```
Time    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
11/1/2014   53438.819   0   1902.19 0   3620.333    12861.2876  0   315.61  0   34739.4 0
12/1/2014   53626.763   0   1908.88 0   3633.066    12906.5207  0   316.72  0   34861.58    0
1/1/2015    50744.951   0   1806.3  0   3437.831    12212.946   0   299.7   0   32988.17    0
2/1/2015    50807.599   0   1808.53 0   3442.075    12228.0237  0   300.07  0   33028.9 0
3/1/2015    50932.895   0   1812.99 0   3450.564    12258.1792  0   300.81  0   33110.35    0
4/1/2015    7264.046    8489.086    258.5685    1465.2215   25465.54    1748.2606   259.5347    42.9015 243.1085    -20251.22   6521.221
5/1/2015    7226.457    8445.158    257.2305    1457.6395   25203.163   1739.214    258.1918    42.6795 241.8505    -20015.83   6487.476
6/1/2015    7245.251    8467.122    257.8995    1461.4305   24940.787   1743.7373   258.8632    42.7905 242.4795    -19739.96   6504.349
7/1/2015    6906.952    8071.77 245.8575    1393.1925   24678.41    1662.3177   246.7763    40.7925 231.1575    -19720.43   6200.644
8/1/2015    7009.4  8191.496    243.1815    1378.0285   24416.033   1693.5511   244.0902    40.3485 228.6415    -19383.71   6340.736
9/1/2015    7019.042    8202.763    243.516 1379.924    24153.657   1695.8806   244.426 40.404  228.956 -19114.42   6349.457
```

I am using the following code (after `melt`ing the data frame to) the generate the plot:

```
p <- ggplot(temp, aes( Time, value)) + theme_bw() +ylab('Monthly Revenue') + xlab('') +
  scale_x_date(breaks=x_breaks, labels=x_labels)
p <- p + geom_area(aes(colour = variable, fill= variable), position = 'stack',alpha=0.6) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        panel.grid.major.y=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        plot.title=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=thousand_formatter) +
  ggtitle('Any Title') + ylab("Dollars")
```

and here's the plot that I get:

[image]

We can see that the negative values are not being displayed properly. How can we display them properly so that the negative values are clearly distinguishable and are under the X axis?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I used the following code now (which is just a hack as stacked area plot shows the cumulative sum, this is also the reason I added negative values to the variable `B` so that the effect of negative values may be offset):

```
temp <- temp[,c(1,11,2:10,12)]
temp[6:11,3] <- temp[6:11,3] + (-1 * temp[6:11,2])
temp <- melt(temp,id='Time')
p <- ggplot(temp, aes( Time, value)) + theme_bw() +ylab('Monthly Revenue') + xlab('') +
  scale_x_date(breaks=x_breaks, labels=x_labels)
p <- p + geom_area(aes(colour = variable, fill= variable), position = 'stack',alpha=0.6) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        panel.grid.major.y=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        plot.title=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=thousand_formatter) +
  ggtitle('Any Title') + ylab("Dollars")
p
```

and I got the following result:

[image]

We can still see that the colors are sorta screwed. Don't know why does pink changes to brown as soon as the values turn negative.

Comment: Using a stacked area plot with negative data doesn't make a lot of sense. How can you draw something with negative area? Do you have any examples of this being done effectively? The plot essentially showing a cumulative sum, in your data the cumsum is never negative so I wouldn't expect anything to go below the x-axis.

Comment: @MrFlick Although I do agree with that it's counter intuitive to make an area plot with negative values, it's possible (with some hacking) to create what the OP is looking for ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25795404/2204410)).

Comment: The pink turns into brown because the brown layer is on top of the pink layer for the negative values.

Comment: @Jaap - yes exactly right. And I'm wondering how to fix that so that the colors are consistent.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no fix for that, it's inherent to an area plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't quite see this as a stacked area plot, but you could create two groups for each variable to partitiion the negative and positive values. Here's a very rough sketch of how you might .

Here I assume your sample data is in a data.frame named `temp`

```
tt<-melt(temp, id.vars="Time")
tt$pos <- tt$value>=0
gg<-expand.grid(Time=unique(tt$Time), pos=unique(tt$pos), variable=unique(tt$variable))
mm<-merge(tt, gg, all=T)
mm$value[is.na(mm$value)]<-0
mm$grp = interaction(mm$variable, factor(mm$pos, levels=c(TRUE,FALSE)))
mm$ymin<-with(mm, ave(value, pos, Time, FUN=function(x) cumsum(c(0,x[-length(x)]))))
mm$ymax<-with(mm, ave(value, pos, Time, FUN=cumsum))


ggplot(mm, aes(x=Time, fill=variable)) + theme_bw() + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(group=grp, color=variable, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), alpha=.6)
```

basically we just create a ribbon chart and do the stacking ourselves. This will eliminate overlapping.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a line plot? It's much better in my opinion, especially with negative values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

temp <- df %>% gather(type, value, -Time)

ggplot(temp, aes(Time, value, group=type, colour=type)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

As you want to make an area plot, I gues you want to show the total as well. You can add that to the plot with:

```
df$all <- rowSums(df[,-1])
```

After that you can make a line plot with extra thick line for the total:

```
ggplot(temp[temp$type!="all",], aes(Time, value, group=type, colour=type)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_line(data=temp[temp$type=="all",], aes(Time, value), colour="black", size=1.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

---

EDIT:

I found a way to hack it into an area plot. Supposing your dataframe before melting is called `df`, you should change the order of the columns first with:

```
df <- df[,c(1,11,6,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,12)]
```

than melt it with (supposing you're using `tidyr`):

```
temp <- df %>% gather(type, value, -Time)
```

after that you can create your plot with:

```
ggplot(temp, aes(Time, value, group=type, colour=type)) + 
  geom_area(aes(colour=type, fill=type), alpha=0.4) +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if there's any way to hack it into creating a stacked area plot. I tried changing the ordering of variables to have the negative variable as the first variable but it screwed up he plot as stacked area takes the cumulative sum. Stacked area plot is much easier to read than a line plot as there are many lines in this figure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I did get to the solution that you posted but this shows multiple variables being negative when only one variable is negative. By looking at this, I tried adding the negative values to the variable at third position thinking the plot would be better. It was slightly better but still not perfect. The color in the negative, was all screwed up and different from the color for the same variable when the values were positive.

Comment: I have edited the question with my updated code now. You may now have a better idea of what I have.

Comment: Because an area plot shows the cumulative sum, it is quite logical that also for other variables the plot will show negative values. With the sample data you provided, it is possible to prevent by picking the right order of the columns. See my updated answer.